# create 100 files containing "1" without for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I was trying to make a script that would create a hundred files called log-01, log-02, log-03 etc containing "1" in each of them without any loops, but it always gave an error "ambiguous redirect

```
#!bin/bash
echo "1">log-{01..100}
```

I tried putting a $ before the log-{01..100} or placing it in quotes but nothing helps.

Comment: How many digits should be in your output? Should it be log-1, log-01, or log-001? And what happens with log-100, can it have 3 digits when everything has only 2 digits?

Comment: fwiw, for larger sequences (eg, 10K, 100K, 1M, ++) a brace expansion is going to require larger chunks of memory and cpu, with the follow-on operations (eg, `tee`, `xargs`) requiring even more system resources; all of these are shortcomings of performing a large number of repetitive tasks at the OS/shell level; for larger operations it may be worthwhilte to see if there are some non-shell solutions that may be more performant (eg, the `awk` solutions in terdon's answer)

Comment: stdout redirection can only go to one file. After all, what should a program do, if the stdout is assigned to a bunch of files???

Answer (score 6):

Output can only be redirected to a single file, not multiple files.

If you want multiple output files, you can use [`tee`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '1' | tee log-{01..99} log-100
```

This will create files named log-01, log-02, …, log-98, log-99, and log-100.

Note that the above will only work with bash starting from version 4.0.
If your bash is older and does not support formatting brace expansions with leading zeros, you can use plain old shell with command substitution:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '1' | tee $(printf 'log-%02d ' $(seq 100))
# or formatting with GNU sed directly:
echo '1' | tee $(seq -f 'log-%02g' 100)
```

This is one of the few use cases where the expansion must *not* be quoted, so it can be field-split after expansion.

Comment: why it creates "log-1", "log-2" etc instead of "log-01", "log-02"?

Comment: @Dair it does not. It creates log-001 through log-100. I just tested it again (bash 5.2). You can try `{001-100}`, maybe that helps

Comment: Support for leading zeros was added in `bash` 4.0.

Comment: If you want `log-001`, you need to use `log-{001..100}` instead of `log-{01..100}`. The OP was using `{01..100}` so knittl, and I, assumed that's what they wanted.

Comment: File names are not set correctly.

Comment: @MohammadShokouhiGol please don't leave such vague comments. If you have found a bug in an answer, _explain what is wrong_ don't just say it doesn't work. What file names are created and what file names did you expect to be created? Note that this won't work if your shell doesn't support the newish `{001..100}` format.

Comment: But `log-{01..100}` expands into `log-001` …`log-100`, the exact same thing as `log-{001..100}`, which is (?) undesired. What you need is `log-{{01..99},100}` to keep it 2-digit until the special case of `log-100` (if that’s what the OP intended). Should it be perhaps `log-{00..99}` instead?

Comment: @terdon, the question wants to start files from 01 but your files start with 001, it's obvious

Comment: Thanks for the hint, updated the answer to generate `log-01`, …, `log-99`, `log-100`. Hopefully that's what the OP really wants. Which is a bit weird, because now the numbers are not aligned: 100 has 3 digits, everything else has 2 digits. Then why not 1, 2, …, 98, 99, 100 in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot redirect to multiple files. You can use `tee`, as already pointed out, or you can do something like this:

```
printf '%s\n' {01..100} | xargs -P 100 I {} sh -c 'echo 1 > log-{}'
```

You can use `-P` to control how many processes to run in parallel.

Or, if you're using a platform that supports it, such as most Linux distributions, you can use GNU `parallel`:

```
printf '%s\n' {01..100} | parallel "echo 1 > log-{}"
```

Or you can use a better tool than the shell, that provides easier ways of doing this. For example, in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=100;i++){print "1" > "log-"sprintf("%.2d",i) }}'
```

You might have a problem with too many open files on some systems, but not if you do this using `gawk` (GNU `awk`). If you can't use `gawk`, try:

```
mawk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=100;i++){file="log-"sprintf("%.2d",i); print "1" > file; close(file)}}'
```

The main advantage of the awk approaches is speed. For instance, if creating 10 thousand files:

```
$ time ( printf '%s\n' {01..10000} | xargs -P 100 -I {} sh -c 'echo 1 > log-{}' )

real    0m4.375s
user    0m20.996s
sys     0m7.308s


$ time ( printf '%s\n' {01..10000} | parallel -j 100 "echo 1 > log-{}")

real    0m12.640s
user    0m21.504s
sys     0m12.414s


$ time gawk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10000;i++){print "1" > "log-"sprintf("%.2d",i) }}'

real    0m0.954s
user    0m0.803s
sys     0m0.148s


$ time gawk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10000;i++){f="log-"sprintf("%.2d",i); print "1" > f; close(f) }}'

real    0m0.133s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.109s
```

As you can see above, `awk` is significantly faster even when running the other tools with 100 jobs in parallel. The shell is *slow*.

Comment: use `mawk2` - i benchmarked it at creating `114,688 files`, and `mawk2` came in at `9609 files/sec` vs. `7682 files/sec` for `gawk -byte-mode`

Answer (score 0):

Your command `echo "1">log-{01..100}` is expanded by bash to the equivalent line:

```
echo "1">log-001 log-002 log-003 log-004 log-005 log-006
```

and that structure is weird/ambiguous/wrong for your purpose.

A good solution is to use the `tee` command as suggested by @knittl. `tee` gets a list of files and writes in them the input received by standard input:

```
echo "1" | tee log-{1..100}
```

Comment: might want to mention that on a large enough number of files you can hit 'Too many open files' errors if `ulimit (-n)` is too low, eg: with `ulimit -n == 3200` ... `echo "1" | tee log-{1..10000} => tee: log-3198: Too many open files`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
seq 100 | xargs -i sh -c 'inputNo=$(printf %02d {}); echo "1" > log-$inputNo'
```

*xargs*  is God's command.

Comment: Easier to just `seq 100 | xargs -i sh -c 'echo "1" > log-$(printf %02d {})'`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution in `bash`:

```
. <(printf 'echo 1 >log-%s\n' {01..99} 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> gawk -p- -be 'BEGIN { 
>
> '"$( jot -w 'print ("1")>(__=sprintf("log-%%05.f.txt",
>                                       %d)); close(__);' 100 )"'
>
> }'
> ```

```
# gawk profile, created Mon Oct 10 14:23:07 2022

# BEGIN rule(s)

BEGIN {
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 1))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 2))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 3))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 4))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 5))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 6))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 7))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 8))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 9))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 10))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 11))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 12))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 13))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 14))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 15))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 16))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 17))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 18))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 19))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 20))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 21))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 22))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 23))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 24))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 25))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 26))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 27))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 28))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 29))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 30))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 31))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 32))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 33))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 34))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 35))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 36))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 37))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 38))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 39))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 40))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 41))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 42))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 43))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 44))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 45))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 46))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 47))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 48))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 49))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 50))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 51))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 52))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 53))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 54))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 55))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 56))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 57))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 58))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 59))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 60))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 61))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 62))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 63))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 64))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 65))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 66))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 67))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 68))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 69))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 70))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 71))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 72))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 73))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 74))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 75))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 76))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 77))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 78))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 79))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 80))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 81))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 82))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 83))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 84))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 85))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 86))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 87))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 88))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 89))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 90))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 91))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 92))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 93))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 94))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 95))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 96))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 97))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 98))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 99))
 1      close(__)
 1      print("1") > (__ = sprintf("log-%05.f.txt", 100))
 1      close(__)
}
```

> ```
> head *
> ```

```
==> log-00001.txt <==
1

==> log-00002.txt <==
1

==> log-00003.txt <==
1

==> log-00004.txt <==
1

==> log-00005.txt <==
1
...
```